# Why doesn't Chrome recognize mobile Blogger templates on the Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7, chrome-for-android

I use Chrome on a Nexus S and a Nexus 7, both with Jelly Bean 4.1.1. When I visit Blogger blogs that use mobile-optimized templates provided by Blogger, Chrome on the phone correctly displays the mobile version of the site, while on the Nexus 7 it apparently doesn't recognize the mobile option and displays the desktop version. To force the visualization of the mobile version I have to append *?m=1* to the blog's URL.

Why doesn't Chrome display the mobile version on the Nexus 7 by default? Is this a Chrome/Nexus 7 issue or a Blogger one?

Here is an example Blogger blog exhibiting the issue:

> http://avventureplanetarie.blogspot.com

It's my blog and uses a Blogger-provided template, with very little customization. All such Blogger blogs I tried behave the same with the Nexus 7, i.e. the desktop version is displayed by default.

Comment: I'd use Wireshark to examine the HTTP request that the browsers are  sending. Perhaps the user agent, or some of the headers, differ, and Blogger is reacting differently accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a concrete example, I can't really tell, but it is likely it's because of the way mobile detection works is usually by screen resolution/size. Nexus 7 may have a screen large enough that the it is being detected as a normal desktop/laptop.

With certain designs, a separate tablet layout may be unnecessary if the site are usable with both mouse and touch input.

Comment: I have updated the question to add a link to an example blog.

Answer (score 1):

When you request a web page using a web browser, your web browser sends `User Agent` string with this request too. Using this string, a website can detect technical specs of user viz. web browser, OS, device etc. In case of Nexus 7, Blogger isn't pushing mobile version. So, better contact Blogger dev team for that. Its a Blogger issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the mobile version to load by appending `?m=1` to the URL:
`http://avventureplanetarie.blogspot.com/?m=1`